# How to Import JQuery iCheck to Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular2-directives

I tried to use iChek library in Angular 4. But When i use it in my TypeScript file, i got an error like : "Property 'iCheck' does not exist on type 'JQuery'"

My Code :

```
   import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
     $(el).iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
     })
  }
}
```

And I want to use this directive in my component like :

```
 <label class="radio icheck-inline menu-label">
                <input type="radio" icheck name="filters.type" value="IN"> Entrant 
            </label>
```

Someone have an issue please for resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective {
    $: any = $;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
         this.$(el.nativeElement).iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx so muchhhhhh

Answer (score 3):

First of all install the following using npm.

```
npm install jquery
npm install -D @types/jquery
npm install icheck
```

After that you should include the iCheck javascript file in the .angular-cli.json

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
         "../node_modules/icheck/icheck.js"]
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thx for your reply .. Yes I installed them .. And I added in my .angular-cli.json, but not worked ..; In ts file when I wrote : `constructor(el: ElementRef) {
     $(el).iCheck({..})`  I have a red marker in iCheck who said : "Property 'iCheck' does not exist on type 'JQuery'" ..

Comment: did you to import icheck  by

`import 'iCheck'`

Comment: Ok i imported it and in my typings.d.ts I added `interface JQuery {
   iCheck(options?: any, callback?: Function) : any;
}` . And I haven't the red marker now .. but when I run app I get `Failed to compile. Property 'iCheck' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.`

Comment: Hmm..That's all needed. Anyway i will check

Comment: Thank you .. For example in this website he explains how to integrate JQuery in TypeScript ... but when i tried it with iChek ..it is not ok https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: @user1814879 i couldn't solve the issue in the correct way. But you can still directly use the jquery as follows

remove the existing jquery and iCheck imports, then 

`declare var jQuery: any;`
Then in the code
`    ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });`

  }
}
'

Comment: Yes it's Ok Thhxx so much ... No Red Marker in iCheck .. Thx .. and for using in component.html I can do => `<label class="radio icheck-inline menu-label">
                <input type="radio" icheck name="filters.type" value="IN"> Entrant 
            </label>`

Answer (score 1):

Install

```
npm install jquery
npm install -D @types/jquery
npm install icheck
npm install -D@types/icheck
```

Add the scripts to /.angular-cli.json file in "scripts" attribute

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/icheck/icheck.js"
],
```

Add the icheck sking in /src/styles.css file

```
@import '../node_modules/icheck/skins/square/blue.css';
```

Now you can use the icheck library in typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { } from 'jquery';
import { } from 'icheck';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  icheck: JQuery;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // call iCheck
    const icheckOptions: ICheckOptions = {
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%'
    };
    this.icheck = jQuery('input').iCheck(icheckOptions);
  }
}
```